# changing property or adding controls dispears suspendlayout() and resumelayout() in designer.cs

Tags: c#, winforms

I found a issue in my C# development.

Here is some detail. I had a window form and two groupcontrols and several buttons and textboxes on the form.

The problem is that once I change any properties of these controls or adding any other controls. These two groupcontrol's .suspendlayout() and .resumelayout() in the .Designer.cs file will disappear silently.

Anyone seen these type of problem before, any reason for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is that a problem? - Perhaps the IDE realizes that they are not needed with the particular property values you have.

Comment: I found out this problem is related with a third party control. Once I registered with license, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

I found out this problem is related with a third party control. Once I registered with license, the problem goes away.